# What is wrong with my CNN?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I really don't understand what is wrong with my model. Sometimes it gives me excellent results, but in other cases results are just absurd. During training, from one moment to another it gives absurd results. I tried model with 3 dropout layers and without them, and get same strange results. Here's my model definition:

```python
batch_size = 1
epochs = 25
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(32, input_shape=(1040,1), kernel_size=100,padding='same',name='ConvLayer1', strides=1))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=70, strides=1, padding='same',name='PoolingLayer1'))
#model.add(Dropout(0.10))
model.add(Conv1D(64, kernel_size=70,padding='same',name='ConvLayer2',strides=1))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=40, strides=1, padding='same',name='PoolingLayer2'))
#model.add(Dropout(0.10))
model.add(Conv1D(128, kernel_size=40,padding='same',name='ConvLayer3',strides=1))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=10, strides=1, padding='same',name='PoolingLayer3'))
#model.add(Dropout(0.10))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1,name='output', activation='linear'))
w = model.get_weights()
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001),metrics=['mse'])
```

Get that kind of results: [Results screenshot](https://ibb.co/feqJr7)

What is happening? And also, do you know how I can improve this model to get better results?

Comment: Looks like it's diverging, I would start with trying a smaller learning rate by a few orders of magnitude, maybe `1e-5` and see if that changes things, if so tune it back up from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Decrease Kernel and Pool Sizes**

From just glancing over your architecture I would say that it's worth trying much smaller values for the pooling and conv filters. The network would have to find a pattern while looking at 100 values at the same time. To put this in perspective, when convolutional nets are used in image processing they have found that kernel sizes of 2-4 are best. You can still look at many data-points all at once in the deeper layers because as they pool together they are looking at deeper combinations of data points.

**Increase Batch Size**

It's very hard for a network to establish a good gradient from a single example. You should be using larger batch sizes, I would start with 32 and move around from there.

**Start with the above changes and then try...**

- Adding another dense layer before your output layer
- Batch normalization between layers
- A different activation function. Not sure what your use-case is but you may need to look at that too to optimize performance

Try something like this to see if it improves.

```
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv1D, LeakyReLU, MaxPooling1D, Flatten, Dense
import keras

batch_size = 32
epochs = 25
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(32, input_shape=(1040, 1), kernel_size=2, padding='same', name='ConvLayer1', strides=1))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=1, padding='same', name='PoolingLayer1'))
# model.add(Dropout(0.10))
model.add(Conv1D(64, kernel_size=3, padding='same', name='ConvLayer2', strides=1))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3, strides=1, padding='same', name='PoolingLayer2'))
# model.add(Dropout(0.10))
model.add(Conv1D(128, kernel_size=3, padding='same', name='ConvLayer3', strides=1))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3, strides=1, padding='same', name='PoolingLayer3'))
# model.add(Dropout(0.10))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, name='output', activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001), metrics=['mse'])
model.summary()
```

**BatchNormalization Example**

```
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization

model.add(Conv1D(32, input_shape=(1040, 1), kernel_size=2, padding='same', name='ConvLayer1', strides=1))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
model.add(BatchNormalization())  # Try adding this after each activation function except the output layer
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=1, padding='same', name='PoolingLayer1'))
```

I would also add early stopping and/or model check-pointing to stop the training once the validation loss stops improving and allows you to load the weights for the best validation loss.

Comment: Why do you recommend add one more dense layer? And also, I don't think that Batch Normalization can improve my model. Can you give me an exemple of batch Normalization Implementation?

Comment: This was just a suggestion after you try the other modifications. I'll add to my answer for the batch-normalization, this is a powerful technique that I would suggest trying.

Comment: And also, if I add another dense layer, how many outputs do you think it may have?

Comment: I would probably start small and try a few varieties. It is always different depending on the problem. Start with 10 perhaps